# Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.HashSet' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException:

Tags: android

I am using latest android studio version and I am facing this issue:

> Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.HashSet' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection()

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 27
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src', 'src/main/aidl', 'src/main/aidl/']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of gradly do you use?

Comment: Did you found any results, buddy?